# R extract data from repetitive text to data frame

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to extract de variables week, year and coment (semana, año y comentario) from this semi and non regular structured text: http://www.virus.uc.cl/virus_respiratorios/aldia/coment_anteriores_reedit.html

I'm able to get weeks and years by

```
a <- readtext("http://www.virus.uc.cl/virus_respiratorios/aldia/coment_anteriores_reedit.html")
sem <- str_match_all(a$text, "(?<=semana [a-zÁ-ú]{0,30} {0,1})[0-9]{1,2}")
año <- str_match_all(a$text,"2[0-9]{3}")
```

but since not all paragraph have de week info I'm getting diferent amount of variables

```
> lengths(sem)
[1] 301
> lengths(año)
[1] 411
```

and i'm not able to return the comment in between titles because the folowing regex return the whole text:

```
(?<=Comentario.*[0-9]{4})((.|\n|\r)*)(?=Comentario)
```

The example output should be like this:

```
   Año Semana
1 2018     46
2 2017     NA
3 2016     44
                                                                                                   Comentario
1       Las consultas por [...whole bunch of thech untill next “Comentario”...] > 14 años (39%).
2       Las consultas por [...whole bunch of thech untill next “Comentario”...] > 14 años (33%).
3 La información de  [...whole bunch of thech untill next “Comentario”...]  influenza B con 30%.
```

Comment: Never use `(.|\n|\r)*` in any regex. It is a very inefficient construct that causes crashes, timeouts, etc. A dot can match any char depending on the regex flavor, flag. In `stringr::str_extract` functions, just prepend the pattern with `(?s)` and `.` will match any char.

Comment: Try `comm <- str_extract_all(a$text, "Comentario(?s).*?(?=Comentario|\\z)")` and then `data <- str_match_all(comm, "Comentario\\s*(?:semana\\s+\\p{L}{0,30}\\s*(\\d{1,2})\\b)?.*?(\\d{4})")`

Comment: from what package is `readtext()`?

Comment: Thanks for the comnest!.. working in the new code... readtext() is from de homonimus package readtext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something. Instead of creating a complex regex we break it up into few steps. The first are splitting the data up by lines and filter out the relevant lines, then the regex is much easier.

```
# Extract text
at <- a[["text"]]
# Split text by line
at_split <- strsplit(at, "\\n+")[[1]] # character vector of lines
# Extract only those lines that start with Comentario and contain at least one number
at_split_com <- at_split[str_detect(at_split, "^Comentario\\s") & str_detect(at_split, "\\d")]


df <- data.frame(
  # Year is just the first 4 digit number preceded by space
  Año = str_extract(at_split_com, "\\s\\d{4}"),
  # Week is assumed to be the first number in the line
  Semana = str_extract(at_split_com, "\\d+"),
  # THe whole line
  Comentario = at_split_com
)


head(df,10)
     Año Semana                                                                                Comentario
1   2018     46                Comentario semanal, semana epidemiológica 46: Del 19 al 25 noviembre, 2018
2   2018     45                 Comentario semanal, semana epidemiológica 45: Del 5 al 11 noviembre, 2018
3   2018     44 Comentario semanal, semana epidemiológica 44: Desde el 29 de octubre al 4 noviembre, 2018
4   2018     41              Comentario semanal, semana epidemiológica 41: Desde el 8 al 14 octubre, 2018
5   2018     39          Comentario semanal, semana epidemiológica 39: Desde el 24 al 30 septiembre, 2018
6   2018     38          Comentario semanal, semana epidemiológica 38: Desde el 17 al 23 septiembre, 2018
7   2018     36         Comentario semanal, semana epidemiológica 36: Desde el 3 al 9 de septiembre, 2018
8   2018     35 Comentario semanal, semana epidemiológica 35: Desde el 27 agosto al 2 de septiembre, 2018
9   2018     30            Comentario semanal, semana epidemiológica 30: Desde el 23 al 29 de julio, 2018
10  2018     28             Comentario semanal, semana epidemiológica 28: Desde el 9 al 15 de julio, 2018
```

Comment: Excellent approach! @snoram ... thanks!!

Make little changes to get the whole comment and not only the first line but the whole comment, and month for the missing weeks data. `strsplit()` was the solution!